# php smtp server

Tags: php, smtp, telnet

I am tring to send an email with PHP through telnet but somthing going wrong here.

```
$telnet = array();
$telnet[0] = "telnet 10.0.50.6 25\r\n";
$telnet[1] = "HELO osiris.com\r\n";
$telnet[2] = "MAIL FROM:$replyTo\r\n";
$telnet[3] = "RCPT TO:$emailsTo\r\n";
$telnet[4] = "DATA\r\n";
$telnet[5] = "From:$headers<$replyTo> \r\n To:$emailsTo\r\n Subject:$emailSubject\r\n        $body\r\n\r\n .\r\n";

@$fp = fsockopen('10.0.50.6', 25);

$count=0;

if (!$fp){
echo 'connection fail';

return false;   
}else{


    foreach ($telnet as $current) {         
    fwrite($fp, $current);
    $smtpOutput=fgets($fp);
    $g=substr($smtpOutput, 0, 3);


        if (!(($g == "220") || ($g == "250") || ($g == "354")|| ($g == "500"))) {
        echo 'connection 2 fail';
             return false; 
    }else{
        $count=$count+1;
        echo $count.'<br>';
        if ($count>5){
            fclose($fp);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**the result is:**

```
telnet 10.0.50.6 25 
220 afcc-ex-il1.rsa-otms.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Sat, 30 Mar 2013 19:01:12 +0000 
220
1
HELO osiris.com 
500 5.3.3 Unrecognized command 
500
2
MAIL FROM:afcc@rsa.com 
250 afcc-ex-il1.rsa-otms.com Hello [10.0.70.22] 
250
3
RCPT TO:cfir@carmeli.me 
250 2.1.0 Sender OK 
250
4
DATA 
250 2.1.5 Recipient OK 
250
5
From:cfir To:cfir@carmeli.me Subject:test test
354 Start mail input; end with . 
354
6
```

Comment: And that "something" is what we are here for to guess?

Comment: Hrm. Well, if it's returning 500 on a HELO, the first thing I'd try is an ELHO instead, to see if it only wants to talk ESMTP. But fundamentally, it actually looks like it's happy enough with the rest of your commands. What problems are you actually having?

Answer (score -1):

You have got everything right but only one extra space
on the following line in the **\r\n .\r\n**

```
$telnet[5] = "From:$headers<$replyTo> \r\n To:$emailsTo\r\n Subject:$emailSubject\r\n        $body\r\n\r\n .\r\n";
```